# Create Own Toolset in Premake5

Tags: premake

I am working with different cross compiler compilers, and an evaluation of premake for GCC has proven to be very successful. 
Now i want to use Premake for cross compiling to different embedded targets and compilers. Is there someone that knows how to extend premake with new compilers, or it is possible already with current functionality in Premake5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already, get the latest source code [from the GitHub project](https://github.com/premake/premake-core). Take a look at the existing toolset adapters in `src/tools`. Read through the "Extending Premake" section of [the project documentation](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki). Ask questions on [the Premake Developer forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/premake-development).

Comment: The "adding a new toolset" section is the only part missing in the "extending" section!

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem possible to select a different toolchain from the command line, nor to add permitted values to the `--cc` option.